# iOS App Preview without iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, quicktime

I have done an iOS App Preview (Video) using iPhone 6 and Quicktime in Yosemite, but I cannot upload it for iPhone 6+ in iTunes Connect, and I don't have an iPhone 6+ Device.

Is there a way to make an App Preview (Video) for iPhone 6+ without the device ?

Comment: Perhaps you can use some third party, (Mac) screen capture software to capture a movie of the iPhone 6+ simulator. There are a few, most are not free, and I don't know their performance (frames dropped, capture audio or not, etc.)

Comment: capturing the simulator will also capture the mouse movement, which is bad.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found a good solution!

In Keynote app, I changed the document size to be the same as iPhone 6+ size and imported the iPhone 6 video and resizes it.
I have resived the video to fit the document and exported it as a video.
That's it!

It is not a perfect solution, but it is good.

Comment: Actually, this just saved my bacon. For some reason ffmpeg always spits out 1081:1920 instead of 1080 which iTunesConnect rejects. I brought the iPhone 6 video into Keynote, manually resized, then exported at 1080:1920. Looks good and is accepted by iTunesConnect. One tip: set all the timings to 0s on export otherwise the video doesn't start right away.

Comment: You saved to me a big headache after hours of useless attempts.

Comment: You sir, are a flipping legend! You just saved my bacon. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm I soon as I realized I had to export and not save. I wish there was a way to stretch the video instead of have the black pillar bars.

Answer (score 15):

Solution how to upscale video using iMovie 10:

1. Create screen recording using QuickTime player. As a result you will have a video with 1334x750 resolution (or 750x1334, depends on screen orientation).
2. Find any **sample** video with resolution 1920x1080 (or 1080x1920). It can be preview of some other application or any other video.
3. Open iMovie 10 and create new App Preview (File -> New App Preview).
4. Drag-and-drop **sample** (from step#2) clip from Finder to the timeline (*first imported clip's resolution will be used in export*)
5. Drag-and-drop your actual video clip from Finder to the timeline.
6. Remove **sample** clip from the timeline (you don't need it anymore, final resolution already set)
7. Click on
8. Select your preview project, Share Project -> App preview

You will see that export resolution will be 1920x1080 (or 1080x1920)

Success! I used this trick several times already.

Comment: Thanks, this actually works for the new size of 886x1920. It's beyond silly.

Answer (score 5):

***Disclaimer: This solution only work for downsampliing, if you know how to upsample video please share it with us***

Hi iphoner, unfortunately you need to record it using a higher resolution device and use [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) to convert your videos.

I used a iPhone 6+ to record the video using Quicktime and encountered the same issue.

To upload a video for iPhone 6+, you need to upload a video with this format size 1920x1080.

[image: Handbreak]

1) Change "Anamorphic" to "custom"

2) unselect "keep aspect ratio"

3) Set the size (width and height) you want (Warning u can only downsample it/ you need a large resolution as your base video)

Other device acceptable formats:

ipad: 1200x900, 900x1200

iPhone 5.5inch/iPhone 3.5inch: 1920x1080,1080x1920

iPhone 4.7inch: 1334x750, 750x1334

For a more comprehensive guide please refer to [this document by apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html)

Comment: The video should be 1920x1080 or 1080x1920 for iPhone 6+. My video size is 750x1330 and the app you mentioned does not support enlarging the video size. So, it does not solve my problem.

Comment: I followed this answer and ran into a problem where HandBrake was not completing the encoding and just jumping to finish exporting a video of just 2 seconds.
I solved this problem by selecting Presets of iPhone & iPod Touch from the top menu before encoding it and it solved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the video from the simulator by running through the following steps.

1. Get your app running in the simulator.
   I believe you will need to run the simulator at 100% scale to ensure 1080:1920

[image]

2. Open up Terminal and run the following command

   > $ xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo /path/Video.mov
3. Switch to your simulator window and run through your demo
4. When you have finished your demo switch back to your terminal window and Press CTL+C to stop the recording
5. Edit the movie in iMovie

   - In order to upload as an App Preview then it will need to be < 30 seconds. You can cut the video down a little, or speed some sections up in order to get it under 30 seconds.
   - Once you have finished editing the movie you can then export it (File->Share->iTunes)
6. This will save it to your iTunes library:
   /Users/marcbeavan/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Home Videos/
7. This file is ready to be uploaded to iTunes Connect
   File info for my video is shown below
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

This command line works perfectly for me every time. It comes from an answer to a similar question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29906477)):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -acodec copy -crf 12 -vf scale=1080:1920,setsar=1:1 output.mp4
```

It will take the input.mp4 file, resize it and output ouput.mp4. You need to install ffmpeg before running the command.

Of course, upscaling leads to quality loss. But if you do not have a Plus screen, this is much better than not having a video app preview at all.

Answer (score 1):

I make a lot of app previews and in all sizes.  The easiest way is to have all the devices, but that's definitely not practical for most people.  You could also edit the dimensions post production to "simulate" the actual device, even iPad.  I would also recommend avoiding the problem all together by having someone like snappdemo.com do it for you pretty cheap.

Comment: as you said, it is not practical. I do not have an iPhone 6+.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any way to record higher resolution, like an iPhone X and need 1080*1920, just follow these steps:

1. Open your higher resolution video in Quicktime.
2. Go to Edit -> rotate right.
3. Go to File -> Export as -> 1080p.
4. Open exported File in Quicktime.
5. Go to Edit -> Rotate Left.

Worked great for me.